# SQL query on Maria DB

Tags: sql, mariadb

i tried to figure out how to do the number 7 query on Helpdesk DB on SQLZOO (medium questions) but I can't. Not even using subquery or not exist statement. Here is the link (n. 7).

http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/Helpdesk_Medium_Questions

Comment: You should describe the problem here rather than linking to it and explain what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

```
select first_name, last_name
from Caller a
left join Issue b
on a.Caller_id = b.Caller_id
where Call_date is null
```

This query says - 
select ALL rows from Caller table regardless of them having a join
select ONLY rows from Issue where they have a join

Therefore, any row that returns from the Caller table that has not made a call will have a null value for Call_date. The where clause says only give me those rows.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use LEFT JOIN on the Issue table and then add a filter where a field in the Issue table is null

```
SELECT ca.First_name, ca.Last_name 
FROM Caller ca
LEFT JOIN Issue i ON ca.Caller_id = i.Caller_id 
WHERE i.Caller_id is null
```